# MSBuild- How to access a target's Property from a PropertyGroup

Tags: msbuild

I am trying to access the Foo Target's "VersionString" property from a PropertyGroup. Is there a way to do this?

```
<Target Name="Foo">
 <ItemGroup>
  <Assembly Include="Foo.exe" />
 </ItemGroup>

 <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.Assembly TaskAction="GetInfo" 
       NetAssembly="@(Assembly)">
   <Output TaskParameter="OutputItems" ItemName="Info"/>
 </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.Assembly>

 <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.TextString TaskAction="Substring" 
       OldString="%(Info.AssemblyVersion)" StartIndex="0" Count="5">
   <Output PropertyName="VersionString" TaskParameter="NewString"/>
 </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.TextString>
</Target>

<PropertyGroup>
 <FooVersion>
  $(VersionString)
 </FooVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property will only be avilable after the target and the specific task have run.

This means that you can only access it in property groups inside targets that run after the task creating the property was run. Your sample tries to access it from a static property group, which is evaluated before any targets are run, therefore the property is not set yet.